# dynamically list sorted thumbnails from filesystem

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sorting, thumbnails

How can I dynamically display a list of 10 thumbnail images that are stored in the file system? The thumbnail images are for videos. This is what I have so far:

- default.aspx, where I have hardcoded the thumbnail links like this:

  ```
  <a id="A1" href="~/PlayVideo.aspx?video=23" runat="server">
          <img id="Img1" src="~/Uploads/Thumbs/Sample.jpg" runat="server" name="go"
              border="0" height="100" width="144" />

  <a id="A2" href="~/PlayVideo.aspx?video=24" runat="server">
          <img id="Img2" src="~/Uploads/Thumbs/Sample2.jpg" runat="server" name="go"
              border="0" height="100" width="144" />
  ```
- clicking on these links loads playvideo.aspx, where I have the code for the player, and video number 23 or 24 (in this case) plays.
- I have a mysql query string that sorts the videos (SELECT file FROM video ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10)

This is what I need to do: 
- Insert the query string into the codebehind (default.aspx.cs) so that the sorted thumbnails show on the page instead of the hardcoded ones. Is this what GridView is used for?

I hope that makes sense. I am using asp.net c#. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The following is my code now:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<VideoDescriptor> vidList = new List<VideoDescriptor>();

        MySqlConnection DBConn = new MySqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand DBCmd = new MySqlCommand();
        DBConn.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = DBCmd.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
            DBCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT VideoID, ImgFile FROM (SELECT VideoID, ImgFile FROM video ORDER BY Rank DESC) as myalias LIMIT 10", DBConn);
            DBCmd.ExecuteReader();

            String ImgFileName;
            Int64 VidID;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ImgFileName = reader["ImgFile"].ToString().Trim();
                VidID = (Int64)reader["VideoID"];
                vidList.Add(new VideoDescriptor() { FileName = ImgFileName,  VideoID = VidID});
            }

        }

        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Response.Write(exp);
        }


        reader.Close();
        DBCmd.Dispose();
        DBConn.Close();
        DBConn = null;

    }

    class VideoDescriptor
    {

        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public Int64 VideoID { get; set; }
    }
```

So I extracted the image file name and the video id, both of which I need for the thumbnail links I pasted above. How do I do this? I know how to just display this info in a gridview, but how do you include the info as part of a url?

Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about that too. There are a few ways to do it I guess, but the best way I can think of would be to add <ItemTemplates> for your <GridView> in the xaml. So, something like this `<GridView><Columns><TemplateField><ItemTemplate><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.VidID") %></asp:HyperLink>` ...etc

Comment: The above should be a step in the right direction. If you are new to data binding and gridviews, I suggest doing some reading on those as you move forward. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx and http://highoncoding.com/Articles/206_GridView_DataBinding.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your best bet would be to define a new class such as

`Private Class VideoDescriptor 
Dim date, thumbPath, videoPath as String
'etc`

Then create a List or some other collection of these descriptors.

```
Dim lstVideos as New List(Of VideoDescriptor)
```

Create your VideoDescriptors in whatever way (i don't know if youre pulling from DB or what) and add them all to the list.

If you modify your SQL query a bit, you can use it as a LINQ query to sort your list:
http://www.devcurry.com/2009/02/sorting-date-in-generic-list-using-linq.html

Then you can use your list as a DataSource for say, a GridView.

```
Dim grdViewVideos as New GridView
grdViewVideos.DataSource = lstVideos
```

The GridView will automatically generate columns based upon each attribute of the items in the list and populate rows based upon each items' data.

This is a bit generic I know, and in VB, but without seeing any of your code I just wanted to give you a few ideas.

Comment: Hi ginman, thanks for the quick response! Is there an advantage to using LINQ? because I am comfortable with mysql queries. The query I have will already give me a sorted list, which I would somehow use to populate grdViewVideos. I'm working on the code and will post it soon...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating image buttons from the code behind, which seems like an easier solution:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection DBConn = new MySqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand DBCmd = new MySqlCommand();
        DBConn.Open();

        try
        {
            DBCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT VideoID, ImgFileName FROM (SELECT VideoID, ImgFileName FROM videos ORDER BY Rank DESC) as myalias LIMIT 10", DBConn);
            MySqlDataReader reader = DBCmd.ExecuteReader();

            String ImgFileName;
            Int64 VidID;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ImgFileName = reader["ImgFileName"].ToString().Trim();
                VidID = (Int64)reader["VideoID"];
                ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton();
                imgBtn.ID = "image_id";
                imgBtn.ImageUrl = "~/Uploads/Thumbs/" + ImgFileName;
                imgBtn.PostBackUrl = "~/PlayVideo.aspx?video=" + VidID;
                placeHolder.Controls.Add(imgBtn);
            }
            reader.Close();

        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Response.Write(exp);
        }

        DBCmd.Dispose();
        DBConn.Close();
        DBConn = null;

    }
```

and the placeholder control in the aspx file where you want the thumbnails to go:

```
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```